# error al instalar angular cli, npm ERR!

Tags: nodejs, angular, angular-cli

Estoy empezando a trabajar con angular, instale el Node js  y todo bien, tengo la versión **v12.20.1**, después ejecute el siguiente comando para el npm: **npm install -g npm** y se instalo la versión: 7.5.4  ,  posterior  ejecute el comando:  **npm install -g @angular/cli** y me salio el siguiente mensaje:

> npm version 7.5.4 detected. The Angular CLI temporarily requires npm version 6 while upstrem issues are addressed

entonces investigue y mencionaba que eliminara la carpeta de npm de la ruta: **AppData/Roaming/npm** y así lo hice, ejecute en mi consola de nuevo el comando **npm -v** y me arrojo la versión: **6.14.10**
y cuando ejecute el comando **ng version**, me sale la leyenda de que "ng" no se reconoce como comando, por lo cual vuelvo a escribir el comando **npm install -g @angular/cli** y me sale lo siguiente:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near "...r" : "0.3.7", npm ERR!

ya ejecute el comando n**pm cache clean --force**, reinicie la maquina y volvi  instalar el angular cli, pero sale el mismo error, como lo puedo solucionar??

me voy a la carpeta npm de la ruta **AppData/Roaming/npm**  y esta vacía

Answer (score -1):

intenta con:
npm install --global npm@6

me dejo de marcar esos errores despues de eso.

un saludo

Comment: Hola @Edwin. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»